# How to Implement Two Factor Authentication Via Email in ASP.Net Core 2?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-2.2, two-factor-authentication, usermanager

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.2 for a web server, In each time a user login to the website, after entering a correct email & password, I need to send a message containing a **4-digits PIN Code** to user email, to use it as Email Two Factor Authentication, and this PIN Code, **should expire after 10 minutes** after sending it.

I can do this manually (generating random PIN Codes, saving them in Database, verifying them using if statements, etc...), this would work, but I created this question to ask how to do this using ASP.NET Core 2 available features (which can spare the database table for me).

I tried [UserManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(TUser, String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.generatetwofactortokenasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2), to generate a token and send it to email:

```
var token = await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, "Default");
SendLoginTokenToUserEmail(user, token);
```

and used [UserManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(TUser, String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.verifytwofactortokenasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to verify it:

```
var verified = await _userManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, "Default", token);
```

This worked perfectly, but my problem was that the generated token wasn't a 4-Digit PIN Code, and its expiration time wasn't 10 minutes (I think the default is 1 day).

So, my Question is: **How to Customize the generated token by UserManager for Two Factor Authentication in ASP.NET Core 2.2?**

Can this done by creating a custom token provider? (I am using Default Token Provider here) if so, what is the steps to do so? I spent hours surfing Docs and ASP.NET Core 2 Articles, but did't find what I need.

*PS: If there is any other way other than UserManager, I am all ears, but I thought this might be the best way, especially UserManager is used everywhere in our system (for login, password-reset, etc...).*

Answer (score 1):

If you need OTP then use "Email" or "Phone" as a tokenProvider

```
var token = await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, "Email");
SendLoginTokenToUserEmail(user, token);
```

And Verify  token using same tokenProvider

```
var verified = await _userManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, "Email", token);
```

> > **The maximum attempts (default is 5)**.

> > **The 2FA codes are generated using Time-based One-time Password Algorithm and codes are valid for six
> > minutes.**